# Structured data for chord progression

Tags: structured-data, microdata, json-ld, rdfa

I want to add structured data for chord progression.

```
    [Chorus]
F                          C
  Welcome to the Hotel California.
       E7                           
Such a lovely place, (such a lovely 
               Am
place), such a lovely face
```

Can I use any property from [MusicComposition](https://schema.org/MusicComposition)? or any other type.

Comment: Why would you want to use structured data for that?  Is there software that will use it to produce guitar tabs or something?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have a website for guitar chords and transpose. So I want to optimize it with structured data that search engine identify this as chords for a song.

Comment: Search engines will be able to tell that your website's about even without structured data based on the word you use for the page. Structured data has almost no impact on SEO beyond rich snippets.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, no major search engines are able to identify musical chords based on structured data. It's best to not bother trying to add specific structured data for musical chords.

Interestingly though, one idea I found to represent chords is to use Schema.org's `HowTo`, where each `HowToStep` represents a section of the song, and each `HowToDirection` instructs the reader to play a specific chord. However, this likely wouldn't result in rich snippets or any other search features from the major search engines, and it definitely wouldn't result in the search engine being able to identify your page's topic any better than it could without the structured data. It's very likely adding such structured data would not help your site in any practical sense.